# Getting Error when inserting records using pdo sqlsrv

Tags: php, sqlsrv

hi am trying to insert records from my form into a table called dbo.[TABLE$Leave Request]. I get this error when i try to submit;

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42S02 
                        [SQLSTATE] => 42S02 
                        [1] => 208 
                        [code] => 208 
                        [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'dbo.TABLE Request'. 
                        [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'dbo.TABLE Request'. ) )
```

My code

```
 if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "leave")) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.[TABLE$Leave Request] 
(dbo.[TABLE$Leave Request].id,
dbo.[TABLE$Leave Request].emp_ID,
dbo.[TABLE$Leave Request].leave_type,
dbo.[TABLE$Leave Request].date_applied,
dbo.[TABLE$Leave Request].leave_days,
dbo.[TABLE$Leave Request].start_date,
dbo.[TABLE$Leave Request].end_date,
dbo.[TABLE$Leave Request].supervisor,
dbo.[TABLE$Leave Request].leave_reason,
dbo.[TABLE$Leave Request].[year],
dbo.[TABLE$Leave Request].partner, 
dbo.[TABLE$Leave Request].phone) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$params = array($_POST[id], 
$_POST[empid], 
$_POST[leave_type], 
$_POST[date_applied],
$_POST[leave_days],
$_POST[start_date],
$_POST[end_date],
$_POST[supervisor], 
$_POST[leave_reason],
$_POST[year],
$_POST[partner], 
$_POST[phone]);

$ins = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql, $params);
if( $ins === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Double-quoted strings perform variable interpolation in PHP](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double). PHP tries to insert the value of a (presumably nonexistent) variable `$Leave` into your string.

Use single quotes instead:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO dbo.[TABLE$Leave Request] 
        (dbo.[TABLE$Leave Request].id,
        ...';
```

Alternatively, escape your `$` character with `\`, i.e. `TABLE\$Leave`.

Comment: Funny how actually reading the error message should have given OP a hint

Answer (score 1):

The error message already says it:

> Invalid object name 'dbo.TABLE Request'.

When you compare this to your code

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.[TABLE$Leave Request]
```

you see `$Leave`, which is replaced by an empty string, giving `TABLE Request`.